# Cannot get Paypal subscribe button to work

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to implement a simple subscribe button using Paypal.
I have used their button generator and then copy pasted that code into my webpage.

The form looks perfectly fine and when I select a package and then click subscribe I need to login to Paypal which also works but then I get this error:

```
The link you used to access the PayPal system is invalid. Check the link and try again.
```

This is my button code. What is wrong?

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXX">
 <table>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
 <option value="Donor">Donor: $5,00 USD</option>
 <option value="Vip">Vip: $10,00 USD</option>
 <option value="Svip">Svip: $15,00 USD</option>
 <option value="Elite">Elite: $20,00 USD</option>
 </select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Minecraft username">Minecraft username</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">

<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/sv_SE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to fill in all settings for my Paypal Company account. Works fine now with above code.